# Inserting into Bigquery table with array of arrays

Tags: google-bigquery

How to insert a record into a BigQuery table with nested arrays 2 levels deep.

ORDER table has an array ORDER_DETAIL which has an array ORDER_DISCOUNTS.

Below is not working.

```sql
INSERT INTO ORDER (ORDER_ID, OrderDetail)
SELECT OH.ORDER_ID, ARRAY_AGG(struct(OD.line_id, OD.item_id, ARRAY_AGG(struct(ODIS.discounttype)) ) 
FROM ORDER_HEADER OH LEFT JOIN ORDER_DETAIL OD, ORDER_DISCOUNTS ODIS 
ON OH.ORDER_ID = OD.ORDER_ID AND ODIS.ORDER_ID = OD.ORDER_ID and ODIS.LINE_ID = OD.LINE_ID 
WHERE OH.ORDER_ID = 'ABCD'
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Looked closely at the SQL code you provided (reformatted) and seems that you also want to JOIN to ORDER_DISCOUNTS ODIS but omitted to include JOIN type and ON clause with field names... 

"... FROM ORDER_HEADER OH LEFT JOIN ORDER_DETAIL OD, ORDER_DISCOUNTS ODIS ..."

Comment: The error I get is "Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed at [1:21]". I changed the select query and used as below.

SELECT OH.ORDER_ID, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(OD.LINE_ID, OD.ITEM_ID , OD.QUANTITY, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(ELIG.LOCATION_ID)))) 
from ORDER_HEADER OH 
LEFT JOIN ORDER_DETAIL OD on OH.ORDER_ID = OD.ORDER_ID  
LEFT JOIN  ELIG ON elig.ORDER_ID = OD.ORDER_ID 
where OH.ORDER_ID = 'ABCD'
GROUP BY OH.ORDER_ID

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the `GROUP BY`s in the sample question. Reproducing here with public data to show how to make arrays of arrays in BigQuery:

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT *
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
JOIN UNNEST(['Andy_K%','Boys%','Catri%']) start
ON title LIKE start
WHERE DATE(datehour) = "2019-09-01" 
AND wiki='en'

)

SELECT start, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(title, views) LIMIT 10) title_views
FROM (
  SELECT start, title, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(datehour,views) LIMIT 3) views
  FROM data
  GROUP BY start, title
)
GROUP BY start
```

[image]